# Flutter error A RenderFlex overflowed. How to set image fit to screen?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to show 2 image in same row like this.

[image]

This is my code.

```
class Page extends StatelessWidget {
  final assetsAudioPlayer = AssetsAudioPlayer();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Flexible(
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Image(
                    image: AssetImage('images/test.png'),
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  ),
                  Image(
                    image: AssetImage('images/test.png'),
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

It have no error when I use small image but when I use large image it show error like this.

```
════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
A RenderFlex overflowed by 156 pixels on the right.
The relevant error-causing widget was
Row
```

How to set image fit to screen?

Comment: wrap your column with expanded widget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try wraping your images in `SizedBox` widget, in addition to change the `fit : BoxFit.fill` into `BoxFit.contain`. This should look like this imo :

```dart
class Page extends StatelessWidget {
  final assetsAudioPlayer = AssetsAudioPlayer();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Flexible(
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: <Widget>[
//Wraping in SizedBox widget
                  SizedBox(
                    height: //specifying whatever height,
                    width:  //and width you want,
                    child: Image(
                      image: AssetImage('images/test.png'),
                      fit: BoxFit.contain,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: //same,
                    width:  //here,
                    child: Image(
                      image: AssetImage('images/test.png'),
                      fit: BoxFit.contain,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```